# How to bind a Shared Parameter to elements of both Type and Instance

Tags: c#, revit-api, autodesk

Using Revit 2018.1 API. I create a Shared Parameter programatically. this works well. I can also bind that parameter to different element types (categories) like Windows or Doors. However, once that is done, I struggle to create a new binding to for example a room which is not a family type, and should be bound to instance

I have got some code that someone provided me. I believe that the part where shared parameter is either created, or a shared parameter is found by name and a bound is created for the category comes from some best practices. HelpParams.cs.

```
//this code is all about finding a parameter
Application app = doc.Application;

DefinitionBindingMapIterator iterator = doc.ParameterBindings.ForwardIterator();

while (iterator.MoveNext())
{
    Definition definition = iterator.Key;

    if (paramName.Equals(definition.Name, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        ElementBinding elementBinding = (ElementBinding)iterator.Current;

        CategorySet categorySet = elementBinding.Categories;

        if (elementBinding.Categories.Contains(elementCategory))
        {
            if (paramType != definition.ParameterType)
            {
                return BindSharedParamResult.eWrongParamType;
            }

            var bindingType = elementBinding.GetType();

            if ((instanceBinding && bindingType == typeof(InstanceBinding)) || (!instanceBinding && bindingType == typeof(TypeBinding)))
            {
                return BindSharedParamResult.eAlreadyBound;
            }
        }

        if (!categorySet.Contains(elementCategory))
        {

            //HK this is the original code that was in the if (!categorySet.Contains(elementCategory)) above
            elementBinding.Categories.Insert(elementCategory);
            if (doc.ParameterBindings.ReInsert(definition, elementBinding))
            {
                return BindSharedParamResult.eSuccessfullyBound;
            }
            else
            {
                WriteToLog("BindSharedParam unable to update category for " + definition.Name);
                return BindSharedParamResult.eFailed;
            }

        }

        return BindSharedParamResult.eAlreadyBound;
    }
    //This code shows how to create new binding for an element category
    CategorySet categorySet = app.Create.NewCategorySet();
    categorySet.Insert(elementCategory);
    Binding newBinding = null;
    if (instanceBinding)
    {
        newBinding = app.Create.NewInstanceBinding(categorySet);
    }
    else
    {
        newBinding = app.Create.NewTypeBinding(categorySet);
    }

    //HK insert success
    var inserted = doc.ParameterBindings.Insert(definition, newBinding);
    if (inserted)
    {
        return BindSharedParamResult.eSuccessfullyBound;
    }

}
```

If I have a parameter I want to create. I have code that will create the Shared Parameter (SP). that works. Also if the first part of the code that tries to find the parameter by name, will first time not find the parameter, and a new binding will be created in second part of code for either type or instance, depending on a input parameter (bool instanceBinding) to the function where this code resides.

So if first element category is Windows. the SP will be created, as well as a new binding of type "NewTypeBinding". all works fine. If I then try to bind the same SP to another type, like Doors, the parameter will be found by name, however the ElementBinding is of type "Type" and not instance. In the case of Doors, that works, and the parameter will be bound.
Then I will try to do the same for a Room element category. Now this is not a family type, thus it has no type information, only instance. The code will find the same parameter, go through code normal flow, but since the only bindingelement available is type, there will be an exception when then the parameter is tried to be bound (inserted)

I have tried some flags and tests, to check if the parameter (bool instanceBinding) is different from the ElementBinding Type from the ParameterBinding that we iterate through. By doing that I can force code execution to go to second part of code where I then try to create a new biding of type "instance". this does not work.
var inserted = doc.ParameterBindings.Insert(definition, newBinding);
inserted is "false".

The opposite will also happen. If I start with Rooms, the first binding will be of type instance. however since types can have instances, code execution will not fail, and the types will have the parameter on instance level instead.

**Is there a way to be able to use ONE Shared Parameter and bind that to both types and instances???**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe not. A shared parameter is bound to either types or instances, not both.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, thank you for answering so quickly. I now tried to do it manually as well through the UI, and got the message that it has already been added, so you unfortunately seems to be right. I am probably not the first to say this, but that is just veird behaviour. I have to create two parameters which has the complete same defintion to add them to different categories.

Comment: Yes. You must take into consideration that the shared parameters functionality was added very early in the Revit lifecycle and was completely oriented toward end user interaction. At the time, the Revit API did not even exist, and was not planned for. On the other hand, extensible storage has been explicitly designed for API use: https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#5.23 ... If you do not explicitly need the end user or Revit to see and manipulate your data, e.g., for scheduling or other purposes, you should consider using extensible storage instead.